# How do I light up the Caps Lock light with xset?

Tags: keyboard, xserver, capslock

I wrote a little fetchmail script that checks the remote server and plays an audio file when I have new mail.  I also wanted to also light up one of my keyboard lights when the mail was available but I ran into a problem.  I am able to light up the scroll lock light with this:

```
/usr/bin/xset led named "Scroll Lock"
```

But I can't light up the Caps Lock in the same way:

```
/usr/bin/xset led named "Caps Lock"
```

I tried specifying the key with a number (1-6) but despite changing the mysterious 'LED mask' (visible with 'xset q') I saw no change to the lights.

Is this broken because I've mapped my Caps Lock key as another Ctrl?

In ~/.Xmodmap I've got:

```
keycode 66 = Control_L
clear Lock
add Control = Control_L
```

I don't want to toggle caps lock, just the light.  Is there a way to do this?

### Further Explanation

This is on a x86 kubuntu lucid machine but I will migrate to debian later.  I'm running the script as a unprivileged user in a python daemon.  Running the same script as root won't work because fetchmail is configured for myself as a user.  And finally, this is all run in a tmux session.

When I began this process I read about setleds but it seems to be restricted to terminals in non x sessions.

Logging in as root and running 'setleds -D +caps < /dev/tty7' works but running 'sudo setleds -D +caps < /dev/tty7' gives me a permission denied error.

The xset command seems perfect for my application, it just refuses to change the Caps Lock light.

Comment: Describe your configuration: OS, machine, etc.

Comment: Well, my caps lock is still caps lock, and running `xset led on` or `xset -led on` doesn't turn it on, even though the documentation says it should turn on all LEDs. So we can probably rule key remapping out.

Comment: You're sudo command is failing because you are not enclosing the shell redirect with the sudo. This will work... $ sudo sh -c 'setleds -D +caps < /dev/tty7'

Answer (score 13):

Execute under root:

`setleds -D +caps < /dev/console`

Hackish, but works for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Does it need to be `xset`? Have you ever used `setleds`?

```
setleds -D +caps
setleds -D -caps
```

Brief overview: [Linux / Unix Command: setleds](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_setleds.htm)

Comment: Halfway there. You just can't do setleds from X.

Comment: @Xyon It allegedly works in X by redirecting input like _setleds -D +caps </dev/console_  , see: https://superuser.com/a/380598/86828

Answer (score 1):

Caps Lock led (not the functionality) OFF

```
for a in `ls -d /sys/class/leds/*caps*`;do echo 0 >$a/brightness;done
```

Caps Lock led (not the functionality) ON

```
for a in `ls -d /sys/class/leds/*caps*`;do echo 1 >$a/brightness;done
```

Answer (score 0):

## `xset` without `root` privileges

Edit `/usr/share/X11/xkb/compat/ledcaps` once using `sed`. This change remains permanent, regardless of any reboots.

```
$ sudo sed -i 's|\!allowExplicit|allowExplicit|g' /usr/share/X11/xkb/compat/ledcaps
```

After logging out and in again, the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> LED can now be controlled without any `root` privileges using the commands:

```
$ xset led named 'Caps Lock'
$ xset -led named 'Caps Lock'
```